# Find usage % of a directory in the disk

Tags: linux, bash, du

How to find the % of disk space used by a directory using du command in linux.

Comment: yes. but couldn't figure out how to find "%".

Comment: Take a look at the `df` command instead.

Comment: df command would give me the disk free and usage of a partition.. but I want the amount of space used by this particular directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a combination of df (file system) and du (file space usage). Just one of these commands won't do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
mydir="/home/user/Downloads"
totalSize=$(du -s -k $mydir | cut -f1)
fileSystemSize=$(df --output=size $mydir | tail -1)
pct=$(echo "scale=2;($totalSize/$fileSystemSize)*100" | bc -l )
echo "$mydir is $pct"%""
```

Is this what you are looking for?

```
/home/user/Downloads is 12.00%
```

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: yes. its tested

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to install packages I recommend [ncdu](https://dev.yorhel.nl/ncdu) - NCurses Disk Usage